# How to count the values of multiple '0' and '1' columns and group by another binary column ('Male' and Female')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I'd like to group the binary information by 'Gender' and count the values of the other/ following fields 'Married', 'Citizen' and 'License'

The below code was my attempt, but it was unsucessful.

```
dmo_df.groupby(['Gender'], as_index = True)['Married', 'Citizen','License'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

[image]

The resulting data frame/ output should look as such:

[image]

Sorry for the poor quality photos.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to get `sum` and not `value_counts`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Gender')[["Married","Citizen","License"]].sum()
        Married  Citizen  License
Gender                           
Female        3        3        0
Male          5        7        4
```

If you want `value_count`, try:

```
>>> df.groupby('Gender').agg({i:"value_counts" for i in ["Married", "Citizen", "License"]}).fillna(0)
          Married  Citizen  License
Gender                             
Female 0      0.0      0.0      3.0
       1      3.0      3.0      0.0
Male   0      2.0      0.0      3.0
       1      5.0      7.0      4.0
```

Comment: I want to count the 0's per each field according to 'Male' and 'Female' and the same for the 1's per each field according to 'Male' and 'Female'. Do let me know if my approach to getting where I want to get is incorrect.

Comment: @Johnnyduke - See the edit